# Configuring socket timeout on amqplib connect in nodejs

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, queue, message-queue

If the RabbitMQ instance if found error then it takes about 120 seconds to timeout before trying to the error

Here is my code used for connecting:

```
         async function connectAmqp() {
            try {
                // Create amqp connection and is there any error then exit with error.
                cluster = await amqp.connect(`amqp://127.0.0.1:5672`,{
                    timeout:2000
                });
                return cluster;
            } catch (error) {
                throw error;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `amqplib`.

The second argument takes the `timeout` value.

It was added in this [PR](https://github.com/amqp-node/amqplib/pull/118)

```
const amqp = require('amqplib');

const connection = await amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', {
  timeout: 2000,
});
```